# What are my ceiling mounting options with this kind of ceiling (old building)?

Tags: lighting, ceiling, mounting, fans

I live in a condo that was converted from a building from the turn of the 20th century, so the ceilings look like this:

[image: Ceiling]

These are not tongue and groove planks. There is a little space between this and the floor above, but it's a little atypical. I've seen people in my building install lights etc. directly onto this, but what are my options if I'm trying to do a ceiling fan?

Comment: I would install on the beam/joist.

Comment: Is that beam decorative, and there are joists above the planks?  I'm not seeing any fasteners.

Comment: I'd be cautious of using this particular junction box. It's attached to a smoke detector and there may be rules about the smoke detector being on its own circuit and not one shared for other uses. Of course, with conduit, pulling a new circuit into this box is dead simple, but you still have to worry about box fill rules.

Answer (score 1):

A fan or light is done just as you have in your pic.

Wire is run in conduit to a box rated for a ceiling fan.

The box is securely mounted to the wood ceiling with 4 #12 1 inch long wood screws

The fan is mounted and wired just as it would be to any fan rated box in any ceiling.

Comment: This is _far_ and away the easiest way of doing things! No worrying about tearing out drywall, running wiring in the direction of the joists above, making repairs, fishing wires. Just do a nice job of running the conduit and mount the thing _anywhere_ you want it!